# How to integrate two or more google-services.json file together for different google FCM service in same project

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I am making a project where I want to integrate different **FCM google-service.json**,how to integrate in same file different project key I tried 2 projects this like but not working we need to add in our project.

```
    {
          "project_info": {
            "project_number": "60554696754247",
            "firebase_url": "https://project-1fca7.firebaseio.com",
            "project_id": "project-1fca7",
            "storage_bucket": "project-1fca7.appspot.com"
          },
          "client": [
            {
              "client_info": {
                "mobilesdk_app_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "android_client_info": {
                  "package_name": "com.company.project1"
                }
              },
              "oauth_client": [
                {
                  "client_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                  "client_type": 3
                }
              ],
              "api_key": [
                {
                  "current_key": ""
                }
              ],
              "services": {
                "analytics_service": {
                  "status": 1
                },
                "appinvite_service": {
                  "status": 1,
                  "other_platform_oauth_client": []
                },
                "ads_service": {
                  "status": 2
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "project_info": {
            "project_number": "13052496681",
            "firebase_url": "https://project-2ebf8.firebaseio.com",
            "project_id": "project-2ebf8",
            "storage_bucket": "project-2ebf8.appspot.com"
          },
          "client": [
            {
              "client_info": {
                "mobilesdk_app_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "android_client_info": {
                  "package_name": "com.company.project2"
                }
              },
              "oauth_client": [
                {
                  "client_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                  "client_type": 3
                }
              ],
              "api_key": [
                {
                  "current_key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                }
              ],
              "services": {
                "analytics_service": {
                  "status": 1
                },
                "appinvite_service": {
                  "status": 1,
                  "other_platform_oauth_client": []
                },
                "ads_service": {
                  "status": 2
                }
              }
            }
          ],

          "configuration_version": "1"
        }
```

Comment: In general, it is ***strongly not advisable*** to modify the google-services.json file. Any reason why you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear exactly what your use case is, but it's worth noting that using the `google-services.json` file is totally optional and in your case you may want to skip it and configure your app manually.

The [documentation here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin) explains how the plugin processes the JSON file.

Basically the plugin creates a `strings.xml` file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <! -- Present in all applications -->
    <string name="google_app_id" translatable="false">1:1035469437089:android:73a4fb8297b2cd4f</string>

    <! -- Present in applications with the appropriate services configured -->
    <string name="gcm_defaultSenderId" translatable="false">1035469437089</string>
    <string name="default_web_client_id" translatable="false">337894902146-e4uksm38sne0bqrj6uvkbo4oiu4hvigl.apps.googleusercontent.com</string>
    <string name="ga_trackingId" translatable="false">UA-65557217-3</string>
    <string name="firebase_database_url" translatable="false">https://example-url.firebaseio.com</string>
    <string name="google_api_key" translatable="false">AIzbSyCILMsOuUKwN3qhtxrPq7FFemDJUAXTyZ8</string>
    <string name="google_crash_reporting_api_key" translatable="false">AIzbSyCILMsOuUKwN3qhtxrPq7FFemDJUAXTyZ8</string>

</resources>
```

Since you're talking about FCM, the relevant pieces are `google_app_id`, `gcm_defaultSenderId`, and `google_api_key`.  If you create strings with those names in your application, Firebase will auto-initialize correctly.

If you want to use multiple apps, as you said, you'll need to manually initialize `FirebaseApp` like this:

```
FirebaseApp customApp = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this, 
       new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
           .setApplicationId(...)
           .setApiKey(...)
           .setGcmSenderId(...)
           .build(), 
       "custom-app-name");
```

Comment: More info is here: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/12/working-with-multiple-firebase-projects-in-an-android-app.html